# SSL certificate validate failed tensorflow docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to dockerize my TensorFlow model and I am getting an error:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)
```

On my local machine my code works great but when I try to run my container I have this error.

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda

RUN conda update --all && pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1

RUN conda install matplotlib

RUN conda install pyqt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgl1-mesa-glx

COPY kerastensorflow.py .

CMD ["python", "kerastensorflow.py"]
```

My model :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import PyQt5
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

...
```

Comment: Hi Cline, can you add the following: `RUN apt-get install ca-certificates` and try again?

Comment: Try to add the line that @RobertoGonçalves says right after `FROM continuumio/miniconda`.